# cGAN: Discriminator loss going to zero while Generator's going always up but the result is very good

Tags: tensorflow, python, generative-adversarial-networks

I have a Conditional Generative Adversarial Network for Quantum State Tomography. The metrics I am monitoring during the training process are the losses and the Fidelity (the degree of similarity between two matrices). Fidelity close to **1** is good and close to **0** is bad. My result is a Fidelity over 0.999 which is excellent but the losses of both Discriminator and Generator are opposite to what I would expect.

Fidelity is continuously rising which means that the matrices being generated by the network are becoming closer and closer to my target:

[image]

But the losses:

[image]

Why is that? Is something wrong or is this acceptable?

What I would expect is the loss of the Discriminator going up - it is becoming harder and harder to distinguish between real and fake data - and the loss of Generator going down. But the opposite happened. I would say "Well, my cGAN is no good and I need to rework it" but the result is good! The Generator is able to generate a matrix that closely resembles the target even though it is becoming worse during training.

Am I not getting something?

Comment: I've never seen a GAN reach equilibrium, indeed usually the stopping criterion is an empirical evaluation of the generator... it's much easier to discriminate to generate, so it's difficult for a generator to keep the pace

Comment: but is this result ok? I mean, I wasn't expecting equilibrium, but I believe that the Generator must have a lower value of its cost function than the Discriminator. The Generator's loss is too high and the disc loss is reaching zero, but the Generator are generating a matrix almost identical to the target. Is this ok? Am I not understanding something about GANs? hehe